# How to extricate tag image from post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have responsive template which working well.

I want to convert it to theme wordpress.

Inside the template there is gallery contains image and description and title link.

- Since the gallery build in the template and everything(responsive) work well.
- I want to embedded/convert the gallery to theme as a post, add link to
- Gallery.js and generate the tag html as it seems in the template.

**The source code of the template:**

```
<!--orginal---------->
                <div class="main">
                    <div id="carousel" class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                        <div class="es-carousel">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="box-1">
                                        <img src="images/page1-img1.jpg" alt="" /> <a href="#">bora-bora</a>
 <span>from $458</span> 
                                        <p>Praesent vestibulum aenean
                                            <br>nonummy hendrerit mauris.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>   
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**I need to generate only the :**

```
<img src="images/page1-img1.jpg" alt="" /> <a href="#">bora-bora</a>
 <span>from $458</span> 
                                        <p>Praesent vestibulum aenean
                                            <br>nonummy hendrerit mauris.</p>
```

[image]

I create new post.

- in the title I write: BORA-BORA
- in the content post I add image from the Media
- under the image I add the description image" Praesent vestibulum aenean
  nonummy hendrerit mauris.".
- in the Excpert I write: from $458

and after this I add code which generate the html tag gallery as you can see below:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div id="carousel" class="es-carousel-wrapper">
            <div class="es-carousel"><ul>

                    <?php $hot_deals = new WP_Query('showposts=2&category_name=hot_deals'); ?>
<?php if($hot_deals->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while($hot_deals->have_posts()) : $hot_deals->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <div class="box-1">
                    <?php the_content(); ?><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <span><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
            </div>          
        </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>         
            </ul></div> 
        </div>  
    </div>
```

the resualt are close but it is not working becose I need :

1. to extract the `<img />` from `<p><a><img /></p></a>`.
2. to take out the `<p>` from `<span><p>FROM $458</p></span>`.

Many thanks How can I do that ?

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="carousel" class="es-carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="es-carousel"><ul>
            <li>
                <div class="box-1">
                    <p><a href="http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/wordpressEng/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/page1-img2.jpg">
                       <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-82" title="page1-img2" src="http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/wordpressEng/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/page1-img2.jpg" alt="" width="219" height="124" />
                       </a>
                    </p>
                    <p>Praesent vestibulum aenean<br />
                    nonummy hendrerit mauris.</p>
                    <a href="#">bora-bora</a>
                    <span><p>FROM $458</p></span>
                </div>          
            </li>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not extracting, since you are just displaying `the_content()`. The only way you could do that without altering theme is that you just have to go to the HTML tab where you are editing your post content and delete the `<a></a>` tag.

But if you can/want to edit the theme you could add a custom meta box with image upload field and then upload image there and not into the content. That way you would have full control over it.